# spring data and neo4j allowed open file problems

Tags: java, spring, centos7, spring-data-neo4j

I am newer with spring-data-neo4j. I created an application that updates a million objects. For this I use Spring Cron to update 10000 nodes each minute. The problem is that the files opened by neo4j does not stop to grow until the bug of the database itself. I tried to increase the number of files that will be opened by a user. But the problem is always present. do you have any idea what can be the probleme ?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are asking. Are you getting an error or a message of some kind? Does something crash?

Comment: when you excute a cypher query.  neo4j open some files to save the change and close them.  but when i run my app. i check the opened file system for neo4j. the number does not stop to grow. from 40000 to 500000 opened file.